# Algorithm to find length and width of rectangle?

Tags: algorithm, math

Given the **diagonal length** of a rectangle, and the **ratio of width to length**, can you offer an algorithm that produces the length and width?

Comment: This is a math problem. math.stackexchange.com is probably a better place.

Comment: I thought about it, but I noticed that algorithm questions are okay.

Comment: Agreed I've flagged this post as off-topic.

Comment: It is not a programming algorithm you're looking for, however. It's a math algorithm.

Comment: diagonal=sqrt(width square+length square)

Comment: @galchen yes, I actually came up with Srikar's solution on my own. But I'm getting the wrong answers. I'm really trying to calculate DPI. But using that algorithm to get the length and width, I wind up with a DPI of 177 pixels per inch for an iPhone 4, which is incorrect.

Comment: see my answer for trigo solution

Comment: @Louis - Edit the question to state your real problem. Show your code. It could be an error in the implementation rather than the algorithm but we don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `D` is the diagonal and `R` is the ratio of `A` to `B`, then `B=sqrt(D*D/(R*R+1))`

Here is why:

[A*A + B*B = D*D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

```
A / B = R , so A = B*R; substituting:
B*R*B*R + B*B = D*D
B*B (R*R + 1) = D*D
B*B = D*D/(R*R + 1)
B = sqrt(D*D/(R*R + 1))
A = B * R
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a jab at this. Say length is 2x and width is 1x. Lets say the diagonal is 10. Using [pythagoras theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) we get -

```
10^2 = (2x)^2 + (1x)^2
```

solving for x we get x = 2root5. with this we get length =2(2root5) & width = 2root5.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

[The arccotangent of the ratio will give you the angle that you can plug into `sin theta = o / h` and `cos theta = a / h`.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry)

Answer (score 2):

Using Pythagorean theorem you get for width w, diagonal d, ratio r

```
w = sqrt( d^2 / (r^2 + 1) )
```

Answer (score 2):

for width w and height h

```
given: d (diagonal), ratio = h/w

     /|
    / |
 d /  |
  /   |h
 /    |
/ X   |
-------
   w

tg(x) = h/w = ratio
x = tg-1(ratio)

sin(x) = h/d
h = d * sin(x)
w = h/ratio
```